# Use the following method to show $GL(n)$ is an open set...

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

Suppose we have $A\in GL(n)$ and $r>0$ with the matrix norm defined as $\|A\|=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R} \frac {|Ax|} {|x|}$

Suppose that $B\in B_{r}(A)$

I want to show that $A^{-1} B \in B_{\|A^{-1} \|r} (I)$

This will eventually lead onto proving that $GL(n)$ is open (I'm assuming it has something to do with the preimage and openness, I'm not sure yet) However I am stuck here

So far I have that I want to show
$\|I-A^{-1}B\|<\|A^{-1}\|r$ ,
using the fact that $\|A-B\|<r$, and potentially that $A$ is invertible in itself, and thus $Ax=b$ has a unique solution, or the fact that $|Ax|\le \|A\|x$ and that $\|A\|<1$ (i.e. a contraction) but I am stuck here, it should be simple enough but I can't get my head around what's to be understood here.

Thanks very much for the help

edit: I can see that all we are doing here is "multiplying" by A inverse, however doing so formally is where I am confusing myself.

Comment: Oh.... thank you for this! I made a mistake in typing out, of course it is defined just with $A$ and not $A^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\|A-B\| < r$, so

$\|A^{-1}\|\|A-B\| < r\|A^{-1}\|$

But your matrix norm is an algebra norm(*), so

$\|A^{-1}(A-B)\|<\|A^{-1}\|\|A-B\|$

Hence

$\|I-A^{-1}B\| < r\|A^{-1}\|$

(*) Proof :

$$\|AB\| = \sup_x \frac{|ABx|}{|x|} = \sup_x \frac{|A(Bx)|}{|Bx|} \frac{|Bx|}{|x|} \leq \sup_y \frac{|Ay|}{|y|} \sup_x \frac{|Bx|}{|x|} = \|A\|\|B\|$$

Comment: thank you so much! it seems so obvious now - I missed the algebraic norm property which gave the solution to this immediately, I appreciate your help

Comment: @user291103 : it's very important to choose wisely the norm you work with. Sure, they are all equivalents, but some are more usefull than other to show stuff

Answer (score 3):

$GL(n)$ is open because it is the inverse image of an open set under $\det: \mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R$, which is continuous because it is a polynomial function.